# Translation of "gesture"

Tags: single-word-requests

I was trying to translate this sentence to Esperanto:

> Buying a present for him would be a nice gesture.

My attempt (feel free to correct it):

> Âceti donacon al li estus agrabla gesto.

But looking at the meaning of `gesto` in Reta Vortaro, it seems that it doesn't have the meaning of "an act or a remark made as a sign of intention or attitude":

> gesto: Ĉiu montra, esprima movo de la korpo, precipe de kapo, brako, mano.

Which word can be used to translate "gesture" in that context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not included in the dictionary it seems that *gesto* can be used with that figurative sense according to [Tekstaro](https://www.tekstaro.com/) (emphasis mine):

> La atmosferon ne plu povis mildigi **ĉarma gesto** de novjorkaj
>   SAT-anoj, kiuj organizis monkolekton por donaci “esperantistan
>   traktoron” al la soveta agrikulturo.

*Esperanto en Perspektivo, Ivo Lapenna, 1974*

---

> Kiel **gesto de bona volo**, Ruslando en aprilo 2014 nuligis 90
>   elcentojn de la nordkorea ŝuldo

*Le Monde diplomatique en Esperanto, Philippe Pons, 2015*

---

Another possibility: *Âceti donacon al li estus agrabla **faro** / **ago***.

Answer (score 1):

I think you attempt

> Aĉeti donacon por li estus agrabla gesto.

is fine. At least in German *Geste* is used for the physical thing as well as figuratively. From English and German we also know the phrase *nice move* / *feiner Zug* what translates to *agrabla movo* or simply *bela ago*.

> Aĉeti donacon por li estus bela/nobla/agrabla movo/ago.

Another possibility to say something similar would be:

> Aĉeti donacon por li estus bonkoraĵo.

Comment: I agree with most of this, except your use of _bonkoreco_; _bonkoreco_ is a quality of how _bonkora_ something is. I think you want _bonkoraĵo_ because  _aĉeti donacon por li_ is something that is characterized by _bonkora_. One can argue about the _bonkoreco_ of _aĉeti donacon por li_ depending on how good the gift is, but the action is a _bonkoraĵo_.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Are you sure about that? I would translate *bonkoreco* as something like *kind-heartedness* while *-aĵo* is a thing imo.

Comment: Try not to think in translations. Even though _bonkoreco_ can be translated to _kindheartedness_, it is only in the context of how kindhearted something is, not something that is kindhearted (i.e., _bonkoraĵo_). Note that the suffix _-aĵ_ does not necessarily need to be an object, but can be any concretization of a concept. Just like _amikaĵo_ can be an act of friendship, and not just some object related to friendship; whereas _amikeco_ is the quality of being friends and expresses the degree of friendship or whether or not there is a friendship.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Yeah, I think you're right since bonkora is an adjective. *-aĵo* and *-eco* are still confusing for me. I thought about *bonkoraĵo* but then decided for *bonkoreco*. Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I made it clearer for you :). Especially in English there is a bunch of overlap when translating words ending in _-aĵ_ and _-ec_. It also took me a while to properly comprehend the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I think `gesto` in the metaphorical, figurative sense should be most clear.
Mind that the stem `gest` can be found in really many European languages, including slavic languages.

Zamenhof used `trajto` but that also has quite other meanings.

> [Zamenhofa] Ago rimarkinda kiel ekzemplo: *admirinda **trajto** de kuraĝo*.